# Set Print-Screen Shortcuts With Script

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

#### Distribution:

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Desktop

#### Question:

I love using the [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) program to take/manage screenshots. However, remapping the print-screen behaviour to the appropriate shortcut keys on every computer is rather tedious. I would like be able to run a script to do this for me and others.

I found [this similar Askubuntu question](/questions/211851/how-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-from-a-script), which appears to want to do the same sort of thing (set shortcuts through the CLI), but unfortunately, it doesn't work for me (yet). I am pretty sure a few things in my script just need tweaking, or perhaps things have drastically changed between 12.10 and 14.04?

#### Script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings shutter --select "['<Shift>Print']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings shutter --full "['Print']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings shutter --active "['<Alt>Print']"
```

#### Example Error output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that custom shortcuts are slightly different and you need to run 3 commands for each. I managed to get it "working" with the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Add the paths for if we are adding rather than overwritting shortcuts
KEY_PATH="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings \
"['$KEY_PATH/custom0/', '$KEY_PATH/custom1/', '$KEY_PATH/custom2/']"

# Now set the shortcuts
BEGINNING="gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings"

$BEGINNING/custom0/ name "Take Full Screenshot"
$BEGINNING/custom0/ command "shutter --full"
$BEGINNING/custom0/ binding "Print"

$BEGINNING/custom1/ name "Grab Active Window"
$BEGINNING/custom1/ command "shutter --active"
$BEGINNING/custom1/ binding "<Alt>Print"

$BEGINNING/custom2/ name "Screenshot Selection"
$BEGINNING/custom2/ command "shutter --select"
$BEGINNING/custom2/ binding "<Shift>Print"
```

Note that **this will overwrite your first 3 custom shortcuts** (if they exist) and you may want to rename `custom0`, `custom1`, `custom2` accordingly in order to not do this.

**One also needs to manually disable the printscreen shortcuts** as shown below (although would be grateful if someone could just update this answers script with the appropriate command(s).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Compiz to set keyboard commands:

> gconftool -t string /apps/compiz/plugins/commands/allscreens/options/command0 -s "shutter --full"
>
> gconftool -t string /apps/compiz/plugins/commands/allscreens/options/run_command0_key -s "< Control>k"

Note: Compiz must be using dconf as the backend.

Comment: Thanks, thats quite helpful. Originally I was using the compiz plugins tool, but every now and then it would get "cleared" for some reason. I wanted to move away from compiz just in case it one day becomes "unsupported".

Comment: It gets cleared almost every time there is an update labeled ubuntu base, which I believe updates compiz unity or both.  This can be worked around by script either every boot or after update of  ubuntu base if you know how.